# How to rendered the images into Carousel in Meteor framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

How to rendered all the images that are in Carousal from room.html into ImgDashboard.html in MeteorJs. I am new in Meteor framework so I need here all the images comes into carousal in meteor template

```
        <!--  **ImgDashboard.js** -->

         Template.ImgDashboard.helpers({
        setImageProcessing: function() {
                var roomId = localStorage.getItem('roomId');/*set localstorage */ 
                var imageData = ImageData.findOne({RoomId: roomId});
/* ImageData collection in Mongodb */ 
                setTimeout(function(){
                var item = "";
                imageData.ImageData.forEach(function(data){
                var base64String = data.ImageString;  

             item += '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" >\
                         <div class="center-block"  width="300" height="300" 
                alt="" >\
                <img src='+base64String+' class= "img-responsive center-
                 block"/>\
                 </div>\</div>'; /* concatenation of images */ 

                  }, function(err){

                 }) 
                $('.image-list').append(item); 

                 },10)   


              });


         <!-- **ImgDashboard.html** -->

            <template name="ImgDashboard">  /* template rendered here to display */
             {{> Header}}
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div> {{setImageProcessing}}</div> /* method from helper */ 
            <div class="image-list">/* images here from helper */ 

            </div>
            </div>
            </template>


      <!--  **Room.html** -->


            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

          <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-
      ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/bedroom-lg.jpeg" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="597">  /* First block */ 
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="images/bedroom-lg.jpeg" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="597"> /* second block */ 
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="images/bedroom-lg.jpeg" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="597"> /* third block */ 
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="images/bedroom-lg.jpeg" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="597">/* fourth block */ 
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="images/bedroom-lg.jpeg" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="597">/* fifth block */ 
              </div>
            </div>

            /* -- Controls -- */
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>  
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a> 
          </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand , you want to reuse your html code, in this case you want to reuse your Carousal.

What you can do is make a template which consists your carousal and call that template inside your `ImgDashboard` template 
like this: 
    {{> carousal}}

Note: I dont think you should store html in your variable like you have done for storing image. What you can do is store the data in an array and iterate in html template using `{{#each}}` loop